# How to handle a complicated state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

**Background**: *I am kind of new to react and am learning it, I have made some sites in it but i Highly doubt my way of appraching the problem.*

So while handaling a complex state .
For example lets say we have a cart which has a product which is a object and then it contains a quantity key now how can we make changes in that quantity, which will be the best way to do it ??

Example

```
const [cart , setcart] = useState([

{_id: "1",
    name:"product1",
    quantity: 2
},
{_id: "2",
    name:"product2",
    quantity: 1
}
]);
```

> lets say we need to update the quantity count of the product with the
> id 2 to 5. What we be the best approach, my way of doing it will be.

```
setcart((items)=>{
const changingItem = items.find((item)=>{return item.id === "2"});
changedItem.quantity = 5;

const newCart = items;
newCart.push(changingItem);

return newCart;
    
})
```

thank you

Comment: I think if you create a map. and put `_id` as the key that would be the fastest way to manipulate the object.

Comment: Can you show how ? to do so.

Comment: Added answer for this

Comment: Ok, now i get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setCart(items => items.map(item => item.id === "2" ? {...item, quantity: 5} : item)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to notify this case of editing an existing product in the list, if you want to add products, you need to check if the item does not exist then push the new product in the array and return a new reference of the array.

```js
const [cart , setcart] = useState([

{_id: "1",
    name:"product1",
    quantity: 2
},
{_id: "2",
    name:"product2",
    quantity: 1
}
]);


setcart((items)=> {
  // first you need to find the index of the target product.
  const itemIndex = items.find((item)=>{return item._id === "2"});
  
  // check if the item exist.
  if (itemIndex !== -1 {
    // Then edit the same object inside the array.
    items[itemIndex].quantity = 5;
  }

  // Create new instance of items array.
  const newCart = [...items];

  return newCart;
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setCart((items) => {
const changingItem = items.find((item)=>{return item.id === "2"});
return [...items, {...changingItem, quantity: 5}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of variable it is. For the example, you mentioned in question if you create a map instead of an array, and put _id as the key that would be the fastest way to manipulate the object.

```
setcart((items) => { items[2].quantity = 5; return {...items}; })
```